# I am getting problem with concatenation of strings

Tags: c, string

In the below for loop when i updating s1 using s2, string length of s1 is not updated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        char s1[20]="this is",s2[10]="book";
        printf("%ld\n",strlen(s1));
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(s2);i++)
        {
                printf("%ld\n",strlen(s1));
                s1[strlen(s1)+i]=s2[i];
                printf("%ld\n",strlen(s1));
        }
        printf("%s\n",s1);
}
```

Output:

7
7
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
this isb

string length of s1 is updated only one time and after that it is not updated because of that concatenation getting error.

How can we ensure this?

Comment: the posted code contains this statement: `s1[strlen(s1)+i]=s2[i];`  The result is undefined behavior as it is trying to assign character(s) past the end of the NUL character in the receiving buffer.  Suggest using `strcat()` or similar operation

Comment: OT: the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` not a `int`.   The resulting execution is error prone as making comparisons between signed values and unsigned values. And trying to assign a unsigned value into a signed value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is in this line `s1[strlen(s1)+i]=s2[i];`

> Lets track the loop to catch the bug

- When `i = 0` and `s1[] = "This is"`
  so `s[strlen(s1)+i] = s2[i]` or `s[7] = s[0]` the result is `s[] = "This isb`
- when `i = 1` and `s[strlen(s1)+i] = s[i]` or `s[8 + 1] = s[1]` the result is `s[] = "This isb\0o"` (note the character 'o' is after the `null` character)

> The trick is here you are summing the string s1 after the size is changed and now a wrong position to the new character

**Solution:** simply rewrite this line `s1[strlen(s1)+i]=s2[i];` to be `s1[strlen(s1)]=s2[i];`

Comment: NO, this is overwriting the string trailing NUL character with some other character.  The result in undefined when executing the `strlen()` function as the trailing NUL char will be found at some (unknown) location further into memory

Answer (score 2):

here you have a very simple one. But fast and efficient :)

```
char *concat(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *saved = s1;           // save it for the return
    if(s1 && s2)                // check if both are not NULL
    {
        while(*s1) s1++;        // go to the end of string s1
        while((*s1++ = *s2++)); // append second string s2
        //*s1 = 0;                // 0 terminate the concatenated string
    }
    return saved;
}
```

If you do not understand something - ask.

You can experiment yourself here
https://onlinegdb.com/B1mE7GaJU

Comment: `*s1 = 0` writes an extra null character to the end of concatenated string.

Comment: @LxerLx indeed :)

Comment: writing an extra NUL character is not a problem as long as the receiving buffer is long enough to contain that extra NUL character

Comment: @user3629249 but is not necessary so I have removed it from the code;

Answer (score 1):

Save strlen(s1) in a variable before starting the loop, then use that variable in `s1[var+i]=s2[i];`.

Also don't forget to null-terminate your new string. An easy way to do this would be to include `s1[var+i+1]='\0';` inside the loop.

Comment: thanks for your response and i tried both s1[var+i]=s2[i] is working but without this s1[var+i+1]='\0' is not working.Here my doubt is why strlen(s1) is not updated in that loop?

Comment: @Deepak See my answer.

Comment: `s1[var+i+1]='\0';` is not necessary _for that code_, because the `s1` array is already padded to the end with null characters by defining it as `char s1[20]="this is"`. That array definition is equivalent to `char s1[20] = {'t','h','i','s',' ','i','s',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're calculating strlen(s1) again and again. When :

1. `i = 0` `strlen` will give 7, thus `s1[7 + 0]` = `'b'`
2. `i = 1` `strlen` will give 8, thus `s1[ 8 +1 ]` = `'o'`

As you may see, you have updated s1[9] directly and skipped s1[8], leading to aforementioned error.

```
    char s1[20]="this is",s2[10]="book";
    printf("%ld\n",strlen(s1));
    size_t offset = strlen(s1);
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s2);i++)
    {
            printf("%ld\n",strlen(s1));
            s1[ offset + i ]=s2[i]; //try this
            printf("%ld\n",strlen(s1));
            s1[ offset + i + 1] = '\0';

    }
    printf("%s\n",s1);
```

Comment: In `printf`, `%zu` should be used to print a value of type `size_t` (`strlen` returns a value of type `size_t`).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main()
{
        char s1[20]="this is",s2[10]="book";
        printf("%ld\n",strlen(s1));

        // some temporary variable
        const size_t t = strlen(s1);

        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s2); i++)
        {
                printf("%ld\n",strlen(s1));

                // some robust protection against buffer overflow
                assert(t + i + 1 < sizeof(s1));
                // add the character 
                s1[t + i] = s2[i];
                // adding the null terminator is not needed
                // when there are fewer characters in string literal then array size
                // the remainder is initialized to 0 implicitly
                // s1[t + i + 1] = '\0';

                printf("%ld\n",strlen(s1));
        }
        printf("%s\n",s1);
}
```

But really, just:

```
strcat(s1, s2);
```

Comment: I know the different logics and predefined functions but i would like to know why it is missing, I need the proper solution.

Comment: @Deepak your code cannot be amended to be good. Just try to write something without calls to the strlen everywhere as in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try this,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        char s1[20]="this is",s2[10]="book";
        printf("%ld\n",strlen(s1));
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(s2);i++)
        {
                printf("%ld\n",strlen(s1));
                s1[strlen(s1)]=s2[i];
                printf("%ld\n",strlen(s1));
        }
        printf("%s\n",s1);
}
```

Since the length is updated each time youre in loop, you can get rid of i.